# Change Browser's security Java Warning

Tags: java, google-chrome

Actually, when i go on a webpage that tries to launch a Java Warning, my Browser (chrome) shows me the warning in my language (italian). Is there a way to have that warning window in english? I've just tried to set English Language on my browser, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

**To change the error message language for yourself:**

view: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml

**Change error message language for everyone:**

not possible since the java application in your browser won't be loaded before you confirm to show it, you could possibly add a placeholder text in english telling the user what the warning message is for and what action they should take.

Comment: It's not that way... for example, if i position the mouse on the star just in the right on the URL textfield i see "Bookmark this page", but if i go on my applet page the warning is shown in italian...

Comment: it might be the language settings for Java in that case, but I'm very certain you can't set the language for this in the application since this might cause a security risk (scammers changing the warning into something positive for example)

Comment: in fact im 100% sure you can't do this in your Java application since the browser won't load it before you confirm to load it, so long story short: not possible

Comment: not possible? lol...not possible! Some people around the world can read it in eng, so i should be able too :)

Comment: you can read it in english if you change your Java locale settings yes, but you can't force it for everyone using your app to show up as english (I assumed that's what you wanted)

Comment: oh yes, of course :D that's what i need! i've seen some posts here on SO, but it didn't work. I have to make a video review of my software, and for it english is a must :)

Comment: I updated my answer to correctly answer your question (and to prevent further confusion)

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me... my windows XP still doesn't change the lang. It says i already have the lang on my pc, i restart but it's the same